# print readable costs from stored decimal

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

Is there a way with PHP to show 2 (or x) decimal places, but not show the .00 if whole number?

I've looked at [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), but it doesn't look like it accommodates this exactly.. though I would like the commas every 3 non-decimal places

```
34.00  => 34
34.7   => 34.70
12424.9=> 12,424.90
```

My numbers are stored as floats w/ 2 decimal places in the database so I don't necessarily need that

Comment: There's also [`money_format`](http://php.net/money_format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is check if it's a whole number first, by rounding it using [floor()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) and checking whether that's equal to the full decimal version.

```
echo (floor($cost) == $cost) ? floor($cost) : number_format($cost, 2, '.', ',');
```

or

```
if (floor($cost) == $cost) {
    echo floor($cost);
}
else {
    echo number_format($cost, 2, '.', ',');
}
```

---

Another option is to use [money_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php):

```
echo (floor($cost) == $cost) ? floor($cost) : money_format('%.2n', $cost);
```

or

```
if (floor($cost) == $cost) {
    echo floor($cost);
}
else {
    echo money_format('%.2n', $cost);
}
```

Comment: That's a good code, but I'd store the result of `floor($cost)` in a variable to prevent computing the same thing twice. :) Besides, it seems fine.

Comment: That really makes no difference whatsoever, floor() is a **very** lightweight function and it's being run just once or twice. (though the idea behind it is good, but more applicable in cases like the parameters of a loop, when it may be run way more times)

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that it's always okay to follow good coding practices. :)

Comment: this (the 1st one more specifically) is nice! I would number_format($cost) on the first one still since I want to still get a comma or two if necessary [the last 2 arguments aren't necessary either since those are the default values]